# How to determine whether a SteamVR_TrackedObject is a Vive Controller or a Vive Tracker

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive, openvr

What is the best way to determine whether a `SteamVR_TrackedObject` is a Vive Controller and a Vive Tracker?

---

**When 0 Controllers and 1 Tacker is paired:**

The Tracker is taken as `Controller (right)` of the `CameraRig`.

**When 1 Controller and 1 Tacker is paired:**

The Tracker is set to Device 2.

**When 2 Controllers and 1 Tacker is paired:**

Creating a third `SteamVR_TrackedObject` and placing it in the `CameraRig`'s `objects` array. Also when a controller looses tracking so does the tracker.

---

In each scenario the Tracker ends up being a different `SteamVR_TrackedObject.index`. What is the best way to check if a `SteamVR_TrackedObject` is a Tracker, or to find which `index` the Tracker is?

Comment: Have you considered using `triggers`?

Comment: @Hristo Can you expand? I'm not sure what you mean? If you are meaning to check if the object has a trigger button, then it wouldn't work. As the tracker has pins (to connect something as a trigger) and uses the same protocols as the controller.

Comment: Omg, I'm sorry I meant to say `tags`

Comment: As in tag certain gameObjects before starting? The issue is that each `SteamVR_TrackedObject` is dynamically set to a device, and I can't predict how it will be assigned. Looking for the best method for talking to the SteamVR and OpenVR APIs.

Comment: Yeah, you could assign different `tags` to different `GameObjects`, that's how you can differentiate them. At least from what I understand from your title. QUOTE: "is a Vive Controller or a Vive Tracker".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only method of checking a `SteamVR_TrackedObject` that I have found yet is to check the `ETrackedDevicePoperty.Prop_RenderModelName_String`:

```
uint index = 0;
var error = ETrackedPropertyError.TrackedProp_Success;
for (uint i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    var result = new System.Text.StringBuilder((int)64);
    OpenVR.System.GetStringTrackedDeviceProperty(i, ETrackedDeviceProperty.Prop_RenderModelName_String, result, 64, ref error);
    if (result.ToString().Contains("tracker"))
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then you can set `SteamVR_TrackedObject.index` to index:

```
GetComponent<SteamVR_TrackedObject>().index = (SteamVR_TrackedObject.EIndex)index;
```

---

Finding any documentation on this has been pretty difficult so far but here's some sources:

- [OpenVR wiki](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/wiki/API-Documentation)
- List of [ETrackedDeviceProperty](http://rust-openvr.github.io/rust-openvr/openvr_sys/enum.ETrackedDeviceProperty.html) values

Comment: Love it. Also note the Oculus touch controller names will contain "controller_left" and "controller_right".

Answer (score 4):

Just stumbled upon this old question and I guess accepted answer was strictly correct when it was asked - there's a direct way to do it now, though: you can use [GetTrackedDeviceClass](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/wiki/IVRSystem::GetTrackedDeviceClass).

It will return value of an enum `ETrackedDeviceClass`. Possible values are:

- `Invalid` - if there's no tracked device under this index,
- `HMD` - if the device is a headset,
- `Controller` - if the device is, well, controller - this is one of your cases,
- `GenericTracker` - this is another one of your cases
- `TrackingReference` - for base stations, supporting cameras etc,
- `DisplayRedirect` - by documentation - *"Accessories that aren't necessarily tracked themselves, but may redirect video output from other tracked devices"*
- `Max` - this one is undocumented and I haven't stumbled upon it yet